# Drupal 7 - Need to alter form value submitted with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I have a view with an exposed filter that is submitting via ajax. The problem is when it submits it is taking a value from the querystring and adding to the values being sent. For example, if ?page=2 is in the querystring it's being included in the ajax headers. I need to alter the ajax headers before it processes so that I get the correct page back, essentially I need to set page=0 in the ajax headers.

I tried hook_ajax_render_alter, but that only alters the commands sent back from the view. And hook_alter_form didn't seem right either.

I was able to get the correct results back by altering the search query using hook_search_api_solr_query_alter but the pager links came back with the wrong link active.

So the essence of my question is, is there a hook that I can use to alter the ajax headers before the view is processed?